# Sql server deadlock with insert, select, delete

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

### Application details

C# web api (implicit concurrency)

dapper for sql execution

### Requirement

When four users are added to a "lounge" it means a game is ready to start. The fourth added user is responsible for starting the game. Once the game has begun the users must be removed from the "lounge".

### Table

UserInLounge (LoungeId, UserId)
Note, there is one more than lounge,

### Code

```
var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
connection.Execute("insert into UserInLounge(LoungeId, UserId, TimeEntered) values (@loungeId, @userId, @timeEntered)", new { loungeId, userId = user.Id, timeEntered = DateTime.UtcNow }, tran);
var userIds = connection.Query<string>("select UserId from UserInLounge where LoungeId = @loungeId", new { loungeId }, tran).ToList();
if (userIds.Count == 4)
{
    connection.Execute("delete from UserInLounge where LoungeId = @loungeId and UserId IN @userIds", new { loungeId, userIds }, tran);
}
tran.Commit();
```

### Problem

Running with more than one user (I use 4 to test) will cause a deadlock in the transaction. I use a transaction because I need to know exactly after the insert if there are now four people and if so remove them.

### 2nd attempt

```
var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
var userIds = connection.Query<string>("select UserId from UserInLounge where LoungeId = @loungeId", new { loungeId }, tran).ToList();
if (userIds.Count == 3)
{
    connection.Execute("delete from UserInLounge where LoungeId = @loungeId and UserId IN @userIds", new { loungeId, userIds }, tran);
    tran.Commit();
}
else
{
    connection.Execute("insert into UserInLounge(LoungeId, UserId, TimeEntered) values (@loungeId, @userId, @timeEntered)", new { loungeId, userId = user.Id, timeEntered = DateTime.UtcNow }, tran);
tran.Commit();
 Log.InfoFormat("{0} added to Lounge: {1}; Now {2} users", user.UserName, ret.Name, userIds.Count);

}
```

With the 2nd attempt the if statement is never true. Here is the log output -

```
|INFO |FiveHundred.Web.Stores.DapperLoungeStore - user3@fivehundred.com added to Lounge: Main; Now 0 users
|INFO |FiveHundred.Web.Stores.DapperLoungeStore - user2@fivehundred.com added to Lounge: Main; Now 0 users
|INFO |FiveHundred.Web.Stores.DapperLoungeStore - user1@fivehundred.com added to Lounge: Main; Now 0 users
|INFO |FiveHundred.Web.Stores.DapperLoungeStore - user4@fivehundred.com added to Lounge: Main; Now 0 users
```

If I add HOLDLOCK as suggested I get a deadlock

```
"select UserId from UserInLounge with (holdlock) where LoungeId = @loungeId"
```

Comment: Since you're in a transaction, why don't you check the count *before* you try to insert (using HOLDLOCK)? Then you don't have to bother with a delete. If the count is already 4, you just don't bother inserting. Doing work only to undo it is wasteful on many levels. (Personally, I would also do this in a stored procedure, that way you don't have to muss with C# transactions on top of database transactions.)

Comment: Also, I don't see the point of selecting all the rows and converting them to a list, just to verify the count. Pseudo-code would be: `BEGIN TRANSACTION; SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM dbo.table WITH (HOLDLOCK) WHERE ...; IF (count) < 4 INSERT...; COMMIT TRANSACTION;`

Comment: So now you don't need the delete, right? This should solve the problem because the select will either return < 4 (and block until the insert is done) or return 4 and skip the insert and go right to commit. That should solve your deadlock issue (but there will always be some level of blocking, and you want that).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks for your help, I have updated the question

Comment: I don't understand your second attempt. User ID 5 comes in, and if users 1, 4, and 7 are already playing, you try to delete the row where user ID = 5? Why are you deleting anything? Why only if the current number of players is exactly 3 (assuming gr.Numplayers = 4, you left that detail out)? Why is this more complex than "if there aren't already 4 players, insert, otherwise do nothing"?

Comment: (Also, about the HOLDLOCK, I would again do that in a single batch with its own BEGIN TRANSACTION in the T-SQL block. I have absolutely no idea what Dapper is doing behind the scenes when you open a transaction in the application code and do those other things; probably nothing good.)

Comment: I'm deleting a collection of users not one - userIds.
Logic -
if 3 in lounge already - delete them all from lounge else insert new user. I updated to code make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from here - http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/

Basically the same as above but plus -

```
var tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
var userIds = connection.Query<string>("select UserId from UserInLounge with (updlock) where LoungeId = @loungeId", new { loungeId }, tran).ToList();
```